# Less overloading mixins with different variable types

Tags: css, less, gradient

I am learning how to use LESS. I have a decent understanding of C++. I would like to create some Mixins for gradients. I started to write mixins for it so that I can just type .gradient( "the start side i.e. top", first color, second color) or .gradient( "the start side i.e. top", first color, first stop, second color, second stop), but for gradients that have 2, 3, or 4 stops. Before I start writing the next one with four colors, I would like to ask if LESS mixins can be overloaded by different variable types. For example:

```
.gradient (top, @top_color, @top_stop, @bottom_color, @bottom_stop){
    background: @top_color;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color @top_stop, @bottom_color @bottom_stop); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(@top_stop,@top_color), color-stop(@bottom_stop,@bottom_color)); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color @top_stop,@bottom_color @bottom_stop); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color @top_stop,@bottom_color @bottom_stop); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color @top_stop,@bottom_color @bottom_stop); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  @top_color @top_stop,@bottom_color @bottom_stop); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@top_color', endColorstr='@bottom_color',GradientType=0 ); 
}
.gradient(@_,@top_color,@top_stop,@bottom_color,@bottom_stop){}
```

The above mixin takes 5 parameters, but the one below does as well.

```
.gradient (top, @top_color, @middle_top_color, @middle_bottom_color, @bottom_color){
    background: @top_color; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color 0%, @middle_top_color 25%, @middle_bottom_color 75%, @bottom_color 100%); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,@top_color), color-stop(25%,@middle_top_color), color-stop(75%,@middle_bottom_color), color-stop(100%,@bottom_color)); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color 0%,@middle_top_color 25%,@middle_bottom_color 75%,@bottom_color 100%); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color 0%,@middle_top_color 25%,@middle_bottom_color 75%,@bottom_color 100%); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color 0%,@middle_top_color 25%,@middle_bottom_color 75%,@bottom_color 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  @top_color 0%,@middle_top_color 25%,@middle_bottom_color 75%,@bottom_color 100%); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@top_color', endColorstr='@bottom_color',GradientType=0 ); 
}
```

(the top mixin's parameters are color, percent, color, percent and the bottom mixin's parameters are color, color, color, color)

Will LESS undestand the difference between the two because the variables are different? 
Or should I find a different route to do this?

EDIT:

is this a good solution or is there a better way?

```
.gradient (top, true, @top_color, @top_stop, @bottom_color, @bottom_stop){
    background: @top_color;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color @top_stop, @bottom_color @bottom_stop); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(@top_stop,@top_color), color-stop(@bottom_stop,@bottom_color)); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color @top_stop,@bottom_color @bottom_stop); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color @top_stop,@bottom_color @bottom_stop); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color @top_stop,@bottom_color @bottom_stop); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  @top_color @top_stop,@bottom_color @bottom_stop); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@top_color', endColorstr='@bottom_color',GradientType=0 ); 
}
.gradient(@_,true,@top_color,@top_stop,@bottom_color,@bottom_stop){}

.gradient (top, false, @top_color, @middle_top_color, @middle_bottom_color, @bottom_color){
    background: @top_color; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color 0%, @middle_top_color 25%, @middle_bottom_color 75%, @bottom_color 100%); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,@top_color), color-stop(25%,@middle_top_color), color-stop(75%,@middle_bottom_color), color-stop(100%,@bottom_color)); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color 0%,@middle_top_color 25%,@middle_bottom_color 75%,@bottom_color 100%); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color 0%,@middle_top_color 25%,@middle_bottom_color 75%,@bottom_color 100%); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color 0%,@middle_top_color 25%,@middle_bottom_color 75%,@bottom_color 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  @top_color 0%,@middle_top_color 25%,@middle_bottom_color 75%,@bottom_color 100%); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@top_color', endColorstr='@bottom_color',GradientType=0 ); 
}
.gradient(@_,false,@top_color,@middle_top_color,@middle_bottom_color,@bottom_color){}
```

Where the second parameter is true if it has stops or false if it doesn't?

Comment: Have you tried to run your code to see if LESS undestands your changes?

Comment: Yeah when I do .gradient (top, blue, 25%, red, 75%) that works properly, but when i do .gradient (top, blue, red, green, blue) that doesn't work properly. Is there a method to make it act upon the type of variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will LESS undestand the difference between the two because the variables are > different? Or should I find a different route to do this?

No, Less does argument matching based on the number of parameters but does not check type of the variables. BUT Less can check the value of a parameter, see http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching

Alternatively you can use guards: http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature with type functions: http://lesscss.org/functions/#type-functions.

```
.gradient (top, @top_color, @top_stop, @bottom_color, @bottom_stop) when (ispercentage(@top_stop)) {}
```

Be careful even when using a guard for the first mixins as above, also the second mixin still match and Less compiles all matching mixins, so you also have to set a guards for your second mixin:

```
.gradient (top, @top_color, @middle_top_color, @middle_bottom_color, @bottom_color) when (iscolor(@middle_top_color)){ }
```

Comment: I am using the argument matching for the direction .gradient(@_, @color, @color). Should I create another one for the stops like this .gradient(@_,@_, color, stop, color, stop). Making the second switch just say "stops" like this: .gradient(top,stops,@color,@stop,@color,@stop) Will that interfere with .gradient(@_,@color,@color,@color,@color,@color) if I went up to 5 colors?

Comment: no that does not work. Try `echo ".m(top){p:top;}.m(@v){p2:@v;}test {.m(top); }" | lessc -` whichs outputs `test {
  p: top;
  p2: top;
}` which means that both mixins match your call

Comment: Can I apply it to the base mixin like so: .gradient((at sign)_, (at sign)color, (at sign)stop, (at sign)end_color, (at sign)end_stop) when (ispercentage((at sign)start_stop)){} instead of applying it to all the others?

Comment: then both / all mixins still match, try `echo ".m(@b) when (isnumber(@b)){p:@b;}.m(@v){p2:@v;}test {.m(1); }" | lessc -
`

Comment: Im not sure if I undestand your last comment, can you put it in the answer?

Comment: I edited my question to see if that answer will work? Will that work like that?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I'm going with:

```
.gradient (top, @top_color, @top_stop, @bottom_color, @bottom_stop) when (ispercentage(@top_stop)){
    background: @top_color;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color @top_stop, @bottom_color @bottom_stop); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(@top_stop,@top_color), color-stop(@bottom_stop,@bottom_color)); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color @top_stop,@bottom_color @bottom_stop); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color @top_stop,@bottom_color @bottom_stop); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color @top_stop,@bottom_color @bottom_stop); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  @top_color @top_stop,@bottom_color @bottom_stop); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@top_color', endColorstr='@bottom_color',GradientType=0 ); 
}

.gradient (top, @top_color, @middle_top_color, @middle_bottom_color, @bottom_color) when (iscolor(@middle_top_color)){
    background: @top_color;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color 0%, @middle_top_color 25%, @middle_bottom_color 75%, @bottom_color 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,@top_color), color-stop(25%,@middle_top_color), color-stop(75%,@middle_bottom_color), color-stop(100%,@bottom_color)); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color 0%,@middle_top_color 25%,@middle_bottom_color 75%,@bottom_color 100%); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color 0%,@middle_top_color 25%, @middle_bottom_color 75%,@bottom_color 100%); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  @top_color 0%,@middle_top_color 25%, @middle_bottom_color 75%,@bottom_color 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  @top_color 0%, @middle_top_color 25%, @middle_bottom_color 75%,@bottom_color 100%); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@top_color', endColorstr='@bottom_color',GradientType=0 ); 
}
.gradient (@_, @var1, @var2, @var3, @var4) {}
```

It seems to work properly for me. Thanks to @Bass